# post request to SOLR in json format with facet using python returns response 400 (Unknown top-level key in JSON request : facet.field)

Tags: python, json, post, solr, facet

I am using python (Django) to post requests to SOLR (9.0.0) in json format ([JSON request API](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/json-request-api.html)) to retrieve the data. When using faceting, I am facing a problem probably due to json format of the request. Can anyone please help?

My aim is to search any two lettered lowercase words (using regex `[a-z]{2}`) from the field 'sentence' from a core.

This query runs correctly from SOLR admin (URL decoded) and gives the desired result:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/lexdb_genl93/select?facet.field=sentence&facet.matches=[a-z]{2}&facet.query=sentence:/[a-z]{2}/&facet=true&indent=true&q.op=OR&q=*:*&rows=0&start=0`

My request json which returns 400 (**Unknown top-level key in JSON request : facet.field**):

```json
{
   "query":"*:*",
   "limit":0,
   "facet":"true",
   "facet.field":"sentence",
   "facet.matches":"[a-z]{2}",
   "facet.query":"sentence:/[a-z]{2}/"
}
```

The python code:

```python
import requests

prerule= '[a-z]{2}'
solr_query= {"query": "*:*", 'limit':0, "facet": "true", "facet.field": "sentence", "facet.matches": prerule, "facet.query": "sentence:/"+prerule+"/"}
solr_headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
resp = requests.post(lexsettings.solr_url+'/query', data=json.dumps(solr_query), headers=solr_headers, auth=(lexsettings.solr_user, lexsettings.solr_pass))
jresp= json.loads(resp.content)
print('solrlist: '+str(jresp))
```

Error portion of the output (of `print` statement):

```json
"error":{
    "metadata":[
    "error-class",
    "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
    "root-error-class",
    "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"
    ],
    "msg":"Unknown top-level key in JSON request : facet.field",
    "code":400
}
```

Thank you for reading this far. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Are you positive that `facet.field` exists and is spelled the same way it is in SOLR?

Comment: Yes. The field exists and the spelling is ok. The query from SOLR admin with the same field name is working.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the query that works is not at all the same as the request you are putting together. You need query-parameters for most of this, so your request should be:

```py
import requests

prerule= '[a-z]{2}'
solr_query= {
    "q": "*:*", 
    'limit':0, 
    "facet": "true", 
    "facet.field": "sentence", 
    "facet.matches": prerule, 
    "facet.query": f"sentence:/{prerule}/"
}

solr_headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

resp = requests.post(
    lexsettings.solr_url+'/query', 
    params=solr_query, # <--------- Note the params kwarg
    headers=solr_headers, 
    auth=(lexsettings.solr_user, lexsettings.solr_pass)
)

print(resp.json())
```

If you truly need to send this as json, then use the `json` kwarg rather than the `data` one:

```py
resp = requests.post(
    lexsettings.solr_url+'/query', 
    json=solr_query, # <---------- Here
    headers=solr_headers, 
    auth=(lexsettings.solr_user, lexsettings.solr_pass)
)
```

Comment: The 'params' kwarg returns docs with all the fields including the full stored value of 'sentence'. Not the two lettered words match as I expect. (The 'json' kwarg returns 0 docs.)

Comment: So it sounds like now you just need to alter the actual query itself. I'm not a solr user, so that is probably best suited to being a new question. But it sounds like the HTTP 400 is resolved

Comment: Yes. The 400 is resolved, but it needs some more refinement to work correctly as the equivalent query is working fine. Still, thanks for your help.

Comment: Since you are not using JSON data params, replacing `'limit':0` with `'rows':0` gives the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the JSON interface, `facet` [refers to the JSON Facet API](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-facet-api.html), and not to the old query string facet interface (see [Supported properties and syntax](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-request-api.html#supported-properties-and-syntax).

Your query should therefore use the JSON Facet API syntax directly under `facet`:

```json
{
  "query": "*:*",
  "facet": {
    "sentences" : {
      "type": "query",
      "q": "sentence:/[a-z]{2}/",
    }
  }
}
```

However, be aware that this will give you a *count of the number of entries* matching your query (which is what a facet query is). From your comment on the other answer, it seems like you want to retrieve all tokens for the field that have two letters.

In that case it might be better to [use the `terms` component](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/terms-component.html#terms-component-parameters):

```
?q=*:*&terms=true&terms.fl=sentence&terms.regex=[a-z]{2}
```

If this is a query you're going to issue often, it might be more effective to do the extraction as a pre-processing step, having a single field that is `sentence_tokens_of_length_2` which only keeps tokens with the wanted length. You can then generate proper facets across that field and get more efficient statistics and filtering instead of having to rely on regex-ing against the whole list of tokens for each request.

But if the query string format does what you want; use that.

Comment: Thank you. The query `solr_query= {"query": "*:*", 'limit':0, "facet": {"sentences": {"type": "terms", "field": "sentence", "regex": "/"+prerule+"/"}}}` is working but the regex is not matched.

Comment: I need the JSON replacement of the SOLR Admin query url stated in the question.

Comment: As far as I know there is no `regex` field for the JSON Facet API - at least its not documented in the reference manual. Which is why I suggested using the terms component instead.

Comment: The `terms` `regex` is not giving the desired result (as in my first comment). So for now I am proceeding with POST request with the `facet` query string.

Comment: I think you've confused the terms _component_ with the `terms` facet type in the JSON Facet API. The Terms component is a completely different thing: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/terms-component.html#terms-component-parameters - but as I mentioned, if the current query string works, just use that - no need to use the JSON format in that case.